# JavaFx on browser

Tags: javafx, webbrowser

Есть ли фреймворки или способ что бы можно было нарисовать интерфейс в JavaFx и все это работало в формате web?

Comment: сомневаюсь в целесообразности создания такого фреймворка

Comment: `WebView` вам в помощь

Comment: @Tsyklop разве webView не просто отображает веб-страницы?
Мне нужно чтоб бы сам интерфейс  который я сделаю через javafx был как web-страница...

Comment: @CloolMear Что значит как web-страница? отображать `html`?